# How can i construct BSTR with embedded NULL character in c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, null, bstr

How can i construct BSTR with embedded NULL character?

Comment: Null characters don't mean anything to BSTRs.

Comment: @Deanna: True, but they do to some of the BSTR functions, such as `SysAllocString` and `SysReAllocString`.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`SysAllocStringLen()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891287.aspx) passing null as the first parameter to allocate the buffer, then fill the body in any way you like. Something like this:

```
BSTR bstr = SysAllocStringLength( 0, desiredLength );
if( bstr == 0 ) {
   //handle error, get out of here
}
for( int i = 0; i < desiredLength; i++ ) {
    if( i % 3 == 0 ) {
       bstr[i] = 0;
    } else {
       bstr[i] = 'A';
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, can you give me an example (I'm a beginner to C++).

Answer (score 0):

Short code snippet

```
BSTR HasNul = ::SysAllocStringLen(L"Who needs\0 embedded like that?", 30);
std::wcout << L"Last character: " << HasNul[29] << "  " << HasNul << L"\n";
```

The `BSTR` has a length of 30, so the last character is `HasNul[29]`, in my example the question mark. The output is

```
Last character: ?  Who needs
```

since the pure C++ method `std::wcout` stops at the first NUL character. As a beginner, do you really need that?